# How to remove semicolon in a string in HIVE SQL

Tags: hive

I am trying to remove ";" semi-colon from a string. 
What command in HIVE SQL should I use. I know regexp_replace may work..but what to put ? 
It appears that ; - the special character does not work but other special characters like , or : works.
For example ,
Data looks like

```
;;;;;0123445
```

I want the data to look like this

```
0123445
```

Any help on this will be appreciated. I have been struggling with this.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I work in UNIX platform to run HIVE SQL Queries

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_REPLACE` indeed looks like a good pick. For example, this removes all semicolons from the field :

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, ';', '')
```

From [the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) :

> Returns the string resulting from replacing all substrings in INITIAL_STRING that match the java regular expression syntax defined in PATTERN with instances of REPLACEMENT.

Please note that the semicolon has no special meaning in the regexp language.

---

If you want to match on semicolons on the beginning of the string only (as shown in your question), use regexp special character `^`, which indicates the beginning of the string

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '^;', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all semicolons, you can simply use `replace()`:

```
replace(my_column, ';', '')
```

To remove leading semicolons, you can use:

```
replace(my_column, '^;+', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hive you need to escape the semi-colon.

```
regexp_replace(column_name,'\;','')
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But I tried using this ..and it gives an error in hive sql in Unix.. ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near regexp_replace...

Comment: Basically, is there a way to replace a special character like ";" in Hive SQL in Unix environment...any help on this will be appreciated...